# loading small version of images at page load

Tags: asp.net, image

I'm using VS2010,C# to develop my ASP.NET web app, I display several big images (around 50KB in size) in a page, and it takes time, of course initially just some small versions of these images are displayed, then user can click on each image and the real size image would be displayed in a lightbox. But as I load the full size images for displaying the thumbnails, it takes a lot of time for loading the page, is there any way that I can load only a small size of each image? is there any way that I can reduce my load time and display thumbnails of images? what are my options, help me please

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way.  If you create a thumbnail on the fly, the whole image has to be loaded, which defeats the purpose.

You could create the thumbnails ahead of time.

Comment: thanks, is there any way that I can create thumbnails on my server (as you said ahead of time), so that these thumbnails are loaded initially?

Comment: There is a popular freeware program called irfanview  that does batch processing of image files.  http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/1028/

Answer (score 1):

you can do two things one create thumbnail and load them rather loading your main images and also you can imply lazy loading means you only load images those are immediately required in viewport that will certainly help your cause.

[Link for lazy loading](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload)

Answer (score 1):

best to use Thumbviewer. It is so easy to use and you'll be surprise how efficient it works.

```
<bri:ThumbViewer ID="ThumbViewer2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Scissors.jpg"
                    Title="Tailors Scissors" ThumbUrl="~/thumbs/Scissors.jpg" Height="75px" Width="90px" ModalImagePadding="40px" />
```

you can find demo here : [Thumbnail-Image-Viewer-Control-for-ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17605/Thumbnail-Image-Viewer-Control-for-ASP-NET-2-0)

Comment: thanks, does it load small versions of images (reduces load time) or just creates thumbnails?

Comment: Yes it does. have you checked the link given above, check the demo. In the example above, if you see ImageUrl="~/images/Scissors.jpg" and ThumbUrl="~/thumbs/Scissors.jpg" field, first thumbs reduced image will be shown and after clicking on that, actual size image.