# Open image on next aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I show image thumbnails on page, Now I want when i click on image thumbnail the big images related to that thumbnail open in IamgeDispData.aspx page where i created a data entry form in that page to enter data related to that picture. How can I do this? With help of query string or else??

Comment: Can you show how you are opening the ImageDispData.aspx? How are you passing the source of image to that page? Any code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Query String is a good option.
What you can do put your image inside a `asp:hyperlink`
Set the URL of asp:hyper link with querysting
And in your detail page get it from url

Note that you can only pass the filepath in the url
And you will have to show it from the physical location

Answer (score 0):

With help of query string ??

**Yes**, you can use it. Just surround  your image with `<a>` anchor tag or use `asp:hyperlink` server side tag.

It can be something like

```
Content/Thumbnails/page.aspx?imageName="your image name"
```

e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.espn.com" target="_blank">
 <img src="ahman.gif" />
</a>
```

Ref:
[html - image links](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlimagelinks.php)
[Hyperlink image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898223/hyperlink-image)
[How to control the image size of a Hyperlink?](http://forums.asp.net/t/994352.aspx/1)

example code snippet:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hlThumbnail" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
  Target="_blank" Style="height: 66px;">
  <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgThumbnail" Height="66px"
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Thumbnail") %>' />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have no issue in showing Id to user , it will be the best solution. In case you have some issue in showing Id , you can encrypt it and then use it as Id. You can also validate then user again in the ImageDispData.aspx if he has the permission to enter the data or not for the image.

I am giving way to use using querystring and javascript.

You can use window.open function of JavaScript to open in new window or tab. When you are generating the thumbnail image , create them with url like : yourBigimage.aspx?photoId=10 , open this url using jquery onclick event of image and use window.open

Comment: You can add one kind of css class to all the images tags. Using jquery $(".classname").on("click",function(event){ window.location : http://www.yourpath?Id=$(this).attr('id') }); On the Id you can put the photoId